# Magento: How do I remove a state from shipping state list but it should display in billing state list

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I am using one step checkout extension for checkout in magento 1.8. I need to tweak my code so that shipping state drop down list hide/remove "virgin island" from state list but it should display in billing state drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue using the paid plugin [region manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/region-manager-remove-disable-or-change-displayed-states-and-regions.html). It's cost $15 but I was able to achieve the client requirement. We can disable states of other countries as well.